# Structure, pointer and binary search tree in c

Tags: c, pointers, struct, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

The below code is able to add only one element to tree.
Please check what is wrong with this code.
I tried creating a binary search tree with 8 nodes with values taken from array, and when I print the tree only the first element is printed i.e the first element of array.
May be I am not good with working of structure and pointer. Can you say more about pointers and structure in c.
I thank for your help.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>                                
struct node{                                              
        int data;
        struct node *left;
        struct node *right;                       
};

struct node *root=NULL;

void add(struct node**,struct node*);

void createtree(struct node **root){
        int arr[8]={20,45,17,56,40,32,25,48};
        int size=sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int);
        struct node *temp=NULL;
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
                temp=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(
struct node));
                temp->data=arr[i];
                temp->left=NULL;
                temp->right=NULL;
                add(root,temp);
        }
}
void add(struct node **root,struct node *temp){
        if(*root==NULL){
                *root=temp;
                return;
        }
        struct node *curr=*root;
        if(temp->data< curr->data){
                struct node *temper=curr->left;
                add(&temper,temp);
        }
        else
        {
                struct node *temper=curr->right;
                add(&temper,temp);
        }                                         
}
void print(struct node *root){
        if(root!=NULL){
                print(root->left);
                printf("%d ",root->data);
                print(root->right);
        }
}                                                                                                   
int main(){                                               
        createtree(&root);                                
        print(root);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code with a debugger?

Comment: The question seems too unclear/broad. At least post example input, desired output, and current output. Explaining what it _can_ do is not a problem description; readers need to know what it _should_ do instead and how that differs.

Comment: Please fix the abominable non-indentation of your code. Try to make it so that only vertical scrolling is needed. Make a [mre].

Comment: Instead of `struct node *temper=curr->left;` `add(&temper, temp);`, you should do either `struct node **temper = &curr->left;` `add(temper, temp);`, or just `add(&curr->left, temp);`. Otherwise, you are modifying a local pointer variable instead of modifying a pointer in the tree. (It would be even better to avoid recursion, IMHO.)

Comment: @wildplasser `add(root,temp)` is not wrong. Check the argument to `createtree`, it's passed by address (e.g. a pointer to pointer) and simply fowarded to `add` as-is.

Comment: @WhozCraig Okay, you are correct. I thought it was the global root. Fre function is overly complex, anyway; no additional variables are needed)

Comment: @wildplasser oh, i concur, if anything that function (a) doesn't need recursion, and (b) should be `add(struct node **, int)`, performing the allocation within.